# just_audio canot play local wav file

Tags: flutter, just-audio

i have been working with `just_audio` package and facing this issue,

> about to play C:\Users\lei\AppData\Local\Temp/XskTmEhFJkqMmDrT.wav, size:26428
> player.**setFilePath**('C:\Users\lei\AppData\Local\Temp/XskTmEhFJkqMmDrT.wav');

this is the error message i got:

> (android platform fails also):
> flutter: UnimplementedError: disposeAllPlayers() has not been implemented.

wav file i used
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sleepreading/res/master/nihao.wav

```
flutter packages:
just_audio:
just_audio_libwinmedia:
```